# how to import and call .Net DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync from ironpython?

Tags: .net, assemblies, ironpython

Does anyone know how to import and access `Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync()` from IronPython?

I have some C# code targeting .Net 4.5 on Win8.1 that I'm trying to port to Iron Python, example:

C# snippet:

```
using Windows.Devices.Enumeration;

DeviceInformationCollection devices= await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync( /* removed */ );
```

However, I just can't seem to import the 'Windows' assembly.

```
clr.AddReference("Windows")
```

results in:

```
IOError: System.IO.IOException: Could not add reference to assembly Windows
```

Does anyone know a way?

Here's my full test case (updated in light of some comments):

```
import clr

clr.AddReference("System.Windows")
clr.AddReference("System.Linq")
clr.AddReference("System.Runtime")
clr.AddReference("System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime")
clr.AddReference("System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime")

print  clr.References

import System
from System.Runtime import *
from System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime import *
import Windows


Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync()
```

Output:

```
(<mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089>,
<System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089>,
<IronPython.SQLite, Version=2.7.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7f709c5b713576e1>,
<IronPython.Wpf, Version=2.7.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7f709c5b713576e1>,
<System.Windows, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a>,
<System.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a>,
<System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a>,
<System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089>,
<System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a>)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "notnet.py", line 17, in <module>
AttributeError: 'namespace#' object attribute 'Devices' is read-only
```

UPDATE:

see: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-winrt-apis-from-desktop-applications

so naively tried it out, I'm not even sure IronPython can import .winmd files, or of the resulting error is a permissions or missing dependency problem:

```
import clr
import sys
sys.path.append(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.VCLibs\12.0\References\CommonConfiguration\neutral")
sys.path.append(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral")
clr.AddReferenceToFile("platform.winmd")
clr.AddReferenceToFile("Windows.winmd")
```

output:

SystemError: Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)

Comment: `System.Windows` maybe?

Comment: that seems to be a different assembly, it doesn't have the 'Devices' sub-namespace.

Comment: Is the `System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll` assembly available to you?  I think that would give you what you would need.

Comment: I can load the assembly, but can't then import the Devices sub-namespace.

Comment: @jeff thanks for the pointer - I've updated my test case but the 'Windows' namespace (according to IntelliSense and perhaps re-enforced by the runtime error) only has Foundation and UI as sub-namespaces.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I can be of much help here, I don't have a Win8/10 machine available currently. [This might be of help](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToCallWinRTAPIsInWindows8FromCDesktopApplicationsWinRTDiagram.aspx).

Comment: No worries @jeff. I used that info when creating the original C# code that I'm trying to port to python, and that magic config setting worked.  Another question would be how todo similar for an Iron Python environment, if it is indeed required.

Comment: I found the following and have updated my original question with the output  https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-winrt-apis-from-desktop-applications

Comment: Wayne did you figure out how to reference Windows.winmd? I'm getting the same error: (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)

Comment: also no, but please see my post in the IronPython mailing list archive for more info: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/ironpython-users/2015-November/017536.html